# does zig cc expose a linker (ld)?

Tags: zig

I am trying to compile [xz](https://tukaani.org/xz/) with `zig cc` on Linux without build tools except zig:

```
$ zig version
0.8.0-dev.1039+bea791b63
$ export CC="zig cc"
$ ./configure
<...>
checking for ld used by zig cc... no
configure: error: no acceptable ld found in $PATH
```

Which is true: system does not have a linker. And zig doesn't advertise one:

```
$ zig cc -print-prog-name=ld
ld
```

Can/does `zig cc` provide a linker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
zig ld.lld
```

for ELF. See [this](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/0cfa39304b18c6a04689bd789f5dc4d035ec43b0/src/main.zig#L2962-L2966) for other formats.

Also see https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/8755 for `zig ld`.